# Any Java functions for blocking non English words?

Tags: algorithm, text-mining, java

Please suggest me the best Java api for removing non English words and blocking incorrect words using

I use an English words list file to parse the given string. The code is responding very slowly. `

```
String englishword;
    while ((englishword = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println("@"+englishword);
        for (String word : wordsArray) {
            //System.out.println("#"+word);
            if(englishword.trim().toUpperCase().equals(word.trim().toUpperCase()))
            {

                linetmp = linetmp.replaceAll(word, " ").trim();
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    if(linetmp!=null)
    for(String nonEnglish:linetmp.split("\\s+"))
    {
        line = line.replaceAll(nonEnglish, "");
    }
    line = line.replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return line;
```

Please suggest me if there is any faster way to do this
Note: i am using Linux OS's dictionary `listy`

Comment: Do you absolutely, positively have to do this in Java?  This application has already been written.  `man strings`

Comment: `englishword.trim().toUpperCase().equals(word.trim().toUpperCase())` can be written as `englishword.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(word.trim())`. I don't know if it improves the performance, it's just a side note

Answer (score 0):

Make trim() and touppercase() of the checked word only once, out of the `for (String word : wordsArray)` cycle.

If you'll do excessive heavy operations in the inner cycle, no API will help you.

You can use a Java API function for searching

```
 import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
 ArrayUtils.indexOf(array, string);
```

Comment: Than you... it is good point. even I feel bettar if I get an API for this. I am expecting a function like {String nonEnglishWord = removeNonEnglishWords()}

Comment: @Java_Dinesh no SUCH functions. Because no java function can work as you wrote here. It is syntactically impossible. You must do your outer cycle yourself. But you can use a function instead of the inner cycle. Look my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code a lot faster<sup>1</sup> by changing the `wordsArray` to a `HashSet`, and using the `contains(String)` method to do the checks.  (Make sure you convert words to upper case when you build the set.)

However, I would point out that this approach doesn't scale.  It is not practical to enumerate all possible "non-English or incorrect" words.  You would be better off building a set containing all of the words that you are prepared to accept, and then eliminating the words not in the set.

---

<sup>1 - Currently, your inner loop takes time that is proportional to the number of words (`N`) in `wordArray`; i.e. `O(N)`.  If you use a `HashSet`, the operation takes `O(1)` time; i.e. roughly constant time.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way.

Create a [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) containing all your elements in `wordsArray` (as lower cases/upper cases).

For each new word `englishword` check if [`set.contains(englishword.toLowerCase())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

This solution runs in `O(n|S|)` pre-processing (creating the HashSet), and checking each word is `O(|S|)` where `|S|` is the length of the string and `n` is number of words in the array, while your solution is basically O(n|S|) per word.

Code snap:

```
public static class EnglishChecker { 
        private final Set<String> set;
        public EnglishChecker(String[] englishWords) { 
            set = new HashSet<>();
            for (String s : englishWords) {
                set.add(s.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        public boolean isWord(String s) { 
            return set.contains(s.toLowerCase());
        }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = { "Cat", "dog", "mousE" };
        EnglishChecker checker = new EnglishChecker(words);
        System.out.println(checker.isWord("cat"));
        System.out.println(checker.isWord("cccccccat"));
        System.out.println(checker.isWord("MOUSE"));

}
```